# Redirecting to Login page using javascript's settimeout() function when server session expires

Tags: javascript, session

After server session expires user must be redirected to Login page. For this purpose using `SetTimeout()` function when the user is inactive for the given Timeout period in web.config.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />

Master Page load 


StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
            script.Append("function expireSession(){ \n");
            script.Append("var jsId = document.cookie.match(/JSESSIONID=[^;]+/);");
            script.Append("if jsId == null) ");
            script.Append("{");
            script.Append(string.Format("window.location='{0}';", ResolveUrl("~/Login.aspx")));
            script.Append("}");
            script.Append("} \n");
            script.Append(string.Format("setTimeout('expireSession()', {0}); \n", this.Session.Timeout * 60000));             
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "expirescript", script.ToString(), true);
```

But it does not work. Please any advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
 {
  base.OnPreRender(e);
   AutoRedirect();
 }

   public void AutoRedirect()
  {
      int int_MilliSecondsTimeOut = (this.Session.Timeout * 60000);
      string str_Script = @"
     <script type='text/javascript'> 
     intervalset = window.setInterval('Redirect()'," + int_MilliSecondsTimeOut.ToString() + @");

   function Redirect()
    {
        alert('Your session has been expired and system redirects to login page now.!\n\n');
        window.location.href='/login.aspx'; 
    }
     </script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Redirect", str_Script);
     }
   }
```

Comment: I want to check if the session actually expired and then Redirect to Login page. Because I am extending the Session when the user is still active (Like filling up the long form) even when the user exceeds timeout period.

Answer (score 0):

review this url

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Automatically-redirect-User-after-Session-Timeout-in-ASPNet.aspx

i hope this may help